# MongoDB updateOne() returns "modifiedCount": 1 for simultaneous update calls on the same document

Tags: mongodb, go, kubernetes

We are trying to update a document using `updateOne()`. The filter identifies the document and we update an attribute of the document using `$set`. This update job is triggered by a cron job every minute.

Say, original document is `{_id: "USER1001", status: "INACTIVE"}`. We update it by calling `updateOne()` using the filter `{_id: "USER1001", status: "INACTIVE"}` and updating the status field as `{"$set":{status:"ACTIVE"}}`. We look at resultant value of `modifiedCount` and expect it to be 1, to claim that the `updateOne()` operation was successful. This then triggers downstream jobs.

The application is running in Kubernetes and we have scaled it. When we test the system under load, two simultaneous `updateOne()` calls are made to the same document with the same filter, from two different pods and both returns `modifiedCount` as 1.

We expect `modifiedCount` to be 1 for one for the pod and 0 for the other. But for some documents we see this result.

*Sample code for reference*

```
// cron job that calls update() every minute

func update(){
  filter := bson.D{{"_id", "USER1001"}, {"status", "INACTIVE"}}
  result, err := collection.UpdateOne(context.Background(), filter, bson.M{"$set": bson.M{"status": "ACTIVE"}})
  
  if result.ModifiedCount != 1 {
    // no update done
  } else {
    // call downstream jobs
  }
}
```

*Sample log lines that we have from the application pods*

- POD-1

> [2020-11-20 17:30:58.610518875 +0000 UTC] [DEBUG] [myJob-7dc8b78bcf-c4677] update() :: Update result :: USER1001 / Matched=1 / Modified=1

- POD-2

> [2020-11-20 17:30:58.409843674 +0000 UTC] [DEBUG] [myJob-7dc8b78bcf-jd7m8] update() :: Update result :: USER1001 / Matched=1 / Modified=1

**Question here is -**

1. Has any one else seen this behaviour?
2. What could be causing this issue?

**Additional info,**

- The application is in Go
- Mongo is 4.4 and
- We are using the latest mongo-driver for go.
- The cron job runs every minute, not on the stroke of a minute. Which means that,

  - POD-1 might run it at,

    - 10:00:23
    - 10:01:23
    - 10:02:23 etc
  - POD-2 might run it at,

    - 10:00:35
    - 10:01:35
    - 10:02:35 etc

Comment: Given the upvoted answer, you should provide a program that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sure. I have update the question with sample code from our app, logs and other info.

Comment: I think if you really expect someone to look into this for you you'll need to provide a complete program that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Closing this question as this was a deep-seated race condition in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you read this document first, find out that it is inactive and then decide to active it, this is a common race condition you have to deal with. Another process does the same thing, and then both update the document.

There are ways to prevent this. Mongodb document level operations are atomic, so the simplest solution for your case is to change your filter to `{_id:"USER1001","status":"INACTIVE"}` to make sure the document is inactive the moment you update it. Then only one node will successfully update the document though multiple nodes might attempt to update it.

Comment: Our filter includes the `"status": Inactive` too. I just didn't mention it.

Comment: The update filter includes status: inactive, or the search filter?

Comment: If you use the update filter you mentioned, then this cannot happen. Document level operations are atomic in mongodb. This could be a driver bug, or there is something else you didn't mention in your code.

Comment: As I said, this cannot happen, so either there is a bug, or there are more details to be heard. There is a lot of production code out there that relies on this behavior. Is there a chance you might be talking to a replicaset? Does the primary fail during an update? If so, inconsistencies may happen.

Comment: I understand that this is not supposed to happen. But we are observing this in our environment and we are clueless after 2 weeks of debugging.
The mongoDB set up that we have is a 3 node cluster.

Comment: Check your mongodb logs around those times you observe the behavior, see if you  have restarts, primary elections, etc.

Comment: No restarts or elections. The DB is being heavily used during the test. And the issue only occurs for 1 in 80 document updates.

Comment: You might want to file a bug report for the driver, and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar requirement in the past. I suggest you try to utilize "locking" mechanism. It prevents another operation while an operation is running.

For reference, please check this: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-select--for-update-inside-mongodb-transactions

Official Docs:

- https://www.mongodb.com/transactions
- https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/

To be noted, as I remember, the Mongo Server should be a "replica set". It can't be a single one.